# Make explicit in UML state diagram that order of activities does not matter

Tags: uml, requirements, state-diagram

Have a UML state diagram describing behaviour of a system by showing the interaction of the user and the system to carry out a use case. This diagram is used as agreement (requirement) with the developers of the system.

When the user request to carry out a use case, the system request information to the user and show error messages if the information is not valid. The system also authenticate the user and show him an error if he is not authenticated.

But it does not matter which activity is done first. It is, which error, information or authentication error, is shown first. We want to make explicit to the developers that the order of activities does not matter though all activities should be done. How we achieve that? I think the "fork" item in state diagram is for this?

Comment: There is no order in use cases. Activities are scenarios in use cases and detail in which order actions take place. A state diagram details behavior for a certain element (class, component, node, what ever).

Comment: Use case is a sequence of actions, including its variations, between a particular actor and system that yields an observable result of value to that actor. Use case diagram link the actor with use case (with the name of the use case). The specification of a use case can be communicated using a state diagram, that contains states and activities that perform a change of state. Of course there is a ordered sequence of activities from initial state to final state in a state diagram, look for state diagram in any search engine.

Comment: A UC is described by _n_ Activities for various scenarios. Each Activity has _m_ Actions where you define the order they take upon some logic. You do that by activity diagrams. Using a state machine would be, well, weird. But maybe you have a UC for it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confusing state machine diagram with activity diagram (and possibly also sequence diagram). The latter has fork (and in sequence diagram there is a way of showing that events are happening in parallel).

The state machine diagram does show the changes of the state and its triggers but is not the main diagram to show related actions nor their flow.
Moreover the entire state machine of an entity typically is influenced by more than one user story. In other words, triggers of state changes can be caused by different use cases. So state machine is across multiple user stories rather than describing just one.

If you try to document flow of use case using state machine diagram, you are most probably doing it wrong.

Comment: State and activity diagrams are equivalent. Both has states and activities. The difference with is that the arrows in the state diagram are the activities and the squares are states, just the opposite of, activity diagram. And state diagram have fork (https://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html#).

Comment: I dont understand what means "entire state machine of an entity influenced by more than a user story". A use case is a interactions betwwen actor and system as a black box and its common to use state diagram to specify the use case. For a given use case, activities transit from initial state to final state having intermediate states between those activities. Acitivities like the user request the system to perform a use case, then system request information to the user, then the user fullfill the information, then the system displays message to the user confirming the operation.

Comment: Describing the interaction between actor and the system is to specify the use case. And you can use state diagram to do that. That interaction has activities (system request some information to the user, or displays some information to the user... ) and so you have the states between  those activities (information displayed, information requested...).

Comment: The fact that you *can* represent states and activities on both state machine and activity diagrams doesn't make them equivalent. You have completely different focus and level of details. State machine doesn't show details of activities, you cannot decompose activity that is there  into more detailed activities (and if you try there is no way you can show the entire respective logic). Also, the arrows in the state machine diagrams are **not** activities, these are *transitions*. An activity can be executed during the transition but doesn't have to.

Comment: State machine is intended to show the entire lifecycle of the object and how its statuses change over time. Now while there are some objects that are created and destroyed during a single use case, they are exception rather than a rule. Even a typical CRUD kind of Use cases indicate that there is on UC to create, another to update, another to delete the object and so on. A state machine of that object should show creation, update (not always) and deletion, all in one diagram. Take for example an order in an online shop.

Comment: You can have use cases like Place order (Actor: Client), Complete order items, Dispatch order (Warehouse worker), Invoice order, Confirm payment, Recognise overdue payments  (Accounting system) and so on. Each of those use cases make just one change of the state and at the same time have a complex internal logic of actions. How would you show those on the state machine diagram (that should be just one for the Order class)? It seems you have some fundamental misunderstanding of the concepts here so I would recommend going through some reading about UML. My last sentence from the answer stands.

Comment: UML is a language. You choose what do you want to communicate with it,  design of the system, business process, whatever... I am talking about to detail the interaction between the system and the actor for only one use case (that is normally called use case specification, that is an activity of RUP methodology) and you talk about orders, classes.... thats not the point. And you can detail the interaction between the user and the system using state diagram being interaction in a initial state and ends in a final state, having preconditions, postconditions, transitions (because activities) etc

Comment: A State Machine is of a Classifier (or to be specific it has Classifier as a Context). A Behaviored Classifier (Use Case is a Behaviored Classifier) is a Classifier. So to clarify - do you describe a State Machine of the Use Case itself (or to be more precise a Behavior invoked in the Use Case)?